# Typesafety with Function varargs as parametrs

Tags: java

I need to write a class with function like this

```
class Converter <T>{

    public <R> R convertBy(Function<T,?>... args){
        Function<T,?> function = args[0];
        // doing something
        return function.apply(t);
    }
}
```

I need this method to be type safe i.e first Function need from args needs to have the same argument type as this class type. For example, if my Converter would be `Converter<String>` I need to check (at the compile time) if the first function has String parameter.

Also, when I wrote method like that is saying that it returns object, and I cannot do

```
int a = converter.convertBy(func1,func2);
```

because is saying that Object is not convertible to int.

-- Edit

Maybe with bigger picture will be easier to get what is it about. So the meaning of convertBy function is that it can with easy combine diffrent operation on different types.

This is working, when I define function like

```
public <R> R convertBy(Function... args)
```

but then It is not type safe. What I need, is to make sure If my Converter is 'Converter ' user cannot pass as first parametr function like
    Function func = (string)->{ return (String)string.length();}

Also I cannot change paramters from

```
convertBy(Function... args)
```

to
    convertBy(Function first, Function... rest)

edit. 
Well I what appeared later is that I can do that. But it still doesn't check.

Thank You.

Comment: Why are you using `Function<T,?>` instead of `Function<T,R>` ?

Comment: In this function is happen something like function concatenation i.e series of function.andThen(args[1]) e.t.c 

I wrote it also like that (with Function<T,R>). But it really is not a problem I need just to make sure that is first function parametr is the same type as class<> type. 

What my compiler then is saying is Object is not convertiable to ... something. And even so, it doesn't check parametr type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to make sure at compile time that your `Function` has return type `R` is to declare it as `Function<T,R>`.

If you also want to accept an unspecified number of other functions with different types, you could write your function like this:

```
public <R> R convertBy(Function<T,R> first, Function<?,?>... others)
```

That way the return type matches the return type of the first function.
But without knowing what you're trying to do with those other functions, it is hard to know what types they are supposed to have.

Comment: I wrote it like that before. When I do so I get the same error, and my IDE is saying something like "Incompatible types. Required List<String> but convertBy was inferred to R".

It works only when I write it like that:

    public <R> R convertBy(Function... args)

Comment: Yeah, type inferrence can be confusing. The function is given type by the context around in the code. That means, by what variable (or formal parameter) are you putting it in. If it's `Function<?,?>`, you have a method with `Object` on input and `Object` on output, too.

Comment: Thank You. But why `R convertBy(Function<T,R>... args) ` return `Object` and `R convertBy(Function... args)` is fine?

Comment: @mhv If this would answer your question if it worked, with ignoring all functions but the first one, varargs are useless. As for the `Object` returned instead of `int`, I think you changed method header like @khelwood suggested. But you kept your `Function<T,?>` variable declaration, rather than changing its type to `Function<T,R>`. If you change it like that, `Integer` will be inferred from the assignment to `int` variable, and type safety will be checked, that means, only Function<T, Integer> won't fail compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it without varargs quite easily actually, all you need to do is to make several methods with different amount of functions in those. This approach is often used for optimization anyway, as varargs aren't nearly as optimized as normal methods.

```
<R> R convertBy(Function<T, R> fnc);
<R,U> R convertBy(Function<T, U> fnc1, Function<U, R> fnc2);
// etc.
```

You can't ensure type safety in an array of `Function`, that is just impossible task. You lose type information there, and the best you could do would be checking the type using reflections, which happens at runtime, thus type safety is not checked compile time.

So I advise just sticking to the `andThen` or `compose` methods unless you have plenty functions and the utility brings you enough syntax sugar to be worth doing it that way.

Comment: Type-safe and with varargs? Well, one possible way is when the functions all have the same type. You could have `Function<T, T>...`, that actually works just fine.

Comment: And I don't understand, why when I add `Function<T,T>` from `Function` it brokes return type. When I add only that every assignment like `int a = converter.convertBy(...)` brokes, it is saying that the return type is Object. Previously code is working.

Comment: `Function<T,T>` requires the input and output to be the same type. If you have `Object` provided to that function and `int` required by the variable you store the output at, it is at a conflicted state. Whatever type it infers, it is wrong on one side.

Comment: Also, if you have it in a `Converter` or `Converter<Object>, the `T` is `Object`. It won't work with integers in `Converter<String>` either, if you want to work with integers, you need `Converter<Integer>` for that.

Comment: Thank You. Yes, I understand that if I declare `Function<T,T>` i need to operate and return the same type. But how make `Function<T,R>` to not returns `Object` in this case? 

I know It's close to ridiculous requirment. My professor came up with something like that, and I know nobody who did that. He claims that it is possible, to check first Function parameter be compatible with class type at the compile type.

Comment: It's not ridiculous at all. You could have last function to make conversion from `T` to `R`, and before that, convert within `T` type. You could have first function convert `T` to `R` and then work with `R` type in all future conversions.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you didn't infer correct type to `R`. As it is generic type of the method, it is inferred by what variable (or formal parameter of some other method) do you store the result in. It shouldn't return `Object` unless you store the output into `Object`. But it is not apparent from the code in the question what could cause this, you didn't post that part there.

Comment: One of the conversions in my case is `String`->`List<String>`->`List<Integer>`->`Integer`. 

If I write `(Function<T,R> first, Function...)` and return type `R` it will be incorrect. When I write it

`public <R> R convertBy(Function<T,?> first, Function...rest)`

and my `Converter` is `Converter<T>` also It doesn't check if first `Function` type and return type of the `Function` is `Object`.

Do you think is there any road to solve It?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158849/discussion-between-mhv-and-vlasec).

Comment: Find out from your professor how this is possible and then write your own answer. I have no answers on how to do that with varargs without disregarding static type-checking. If there is a way and your professor is truly a genius, I'll be glad to learn something new.

Comment: I am really curious too. Okay, as soon as I find out how is that possible I will write my own answer. Cheers!